# When a Facebook user sends the Send dialog within an application, can the application track the recipients?

Tags: facebook, dialog, send

When users open a Send dialog (e.g. http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response) they can add or remove people from the To: line.

Is there a way for the application to track who was in the To: line if and when the user actually pushes Send?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.
At least not currently...

If you look at the official documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/ then you can see that this type of dialog does not expect a callback function as a parameter, and since there's no callback function then you have no way of knowing who and/or how many recipients were, and even if the dialog is closed/canceled/sent.

What you can do, though seems very complicated and well, a headache, is to use the outbox connection of the User object in the graph api (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).
I've never used that before, but I guess that you can (if you ask for the read_mailbox permission) check the user messages before and after the dialog, and see what changed.

Comment: While this is technically correct, there are definitely ways to get around it. I happened to notice that the dating site Coffee Meets Bagel was rewarding users for sending invite messages to their friends and was curious how they were doing it. After looking into it, it seems that they attach their own click event to the publish button in the Facebook dialogue, which submits a separate POST to their server. This way you can detect whether someone has sent a message using the dialogue. Only problem is you don't know who they sent it to, if anyone.

Comment: The problem with this type of approach is that you are depended on the FB ui elements, and unlike their APIs they can change that when ever they want to without informing you or anyone else..  In such a case, all of the sudden things in your system can stop working with out you knowing where and why it happened, and you can spend much time figuring out that facebook decided to change their DOM.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, could you help with this, it also is related with this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654709/facebook-sdk-send-method-in-reactjs

Comment: @Asking sorry, i haven't been dealing with the fb apis for a few years now