# js | facebook api | get recipients from send dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

duplicate for [When a Facebook user sends the Send dialog within an application, can the application track the recipients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298214/when-a-facebook-user-sends-the-send-dialog-within-an-application-can-the-applic) but that question in too old.

```
// calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method: 'send',
        to: '',
        link: 'http://snow.sa-wd.ru',
        picture: 'http://snow.sa-wd.ru/images/preview-greeting.webp',
        name: 'test',
        caption: 'Submit to friend',
        description: 'Using Dialogs for posting to friends timeline.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
```

how can I get names of recipients?

Answer (score 0):

You can´t get information about the recipients:

> There is no response data from this dialog.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: oh, that´s not possible at all. i will change my answer, sorry for the confusion.